# AutoHotkey - WinWaitClose with Chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

How can i make `winwaitclose` work with chrome tabs?

I've tried:

```
Run chrome.exe web.whatsapp.com
sleep, 2000
WinWait, WhatsApp - Google Chrome
WinWaitClose 
{some code}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

And how would i do it for multiple tabs?

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn`t work? What do you expect to happen after the window is closed?

Comment: I expect to run any kind of code, for this matter could be msgbox, Hello World, but i didn't recognize the closed tab, that`s why it didn't work

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for multi-tabbed windows. I don't know why either. You can use `WinWaitClose, WhatsApp - Google Chrome` instead, but it will also work if you activate another tab in the same window. Good question! (+1)

Comment: It doesn't work for tabs, windows yes, processes yes, tabs no. Period.